# how to make a solution from server hosted files

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-6

I have a old website which running on iis6.
I have the hosted files in the virtual directory of this hosted website.
But I lost all the solution or project files which can be opened in visual studio 2003 for modification of this website.

Since it is missing I am thinking to make the solution file, .SLN file from the files resides in virtual directory and open this in visual studio 2003 for further modification.

Any idea how to create solution file from virtual directory files?

Comment: is it a website or web application? Are you able to see .cs files in hosted files?

Comment: Yes it is web application, I can see cs files in that

Comment: If you able to see the .cs files in hosted files then it is a type of website template.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a solution file by following steps.

1) Open visual studio

2) click on File -> Open -> Website --> File system dialogue will open

3) Navigate to your hosted files root folder and select folder --> Click on open

4) So your solution will be prepared by visual studio

5) Click on file-> save

Thats it, visual studio will create .sln file for you.

Cheers,
Vijay